# Replacing \n with <br> tags

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have some user provided text which I'd like to display correctly in browser (with new lines replaced with `<br/>`-tags). I wish to have every other HTML tag escaped. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is really hard to help without some code provided. In my experience even String values with \n appear correctly in the browser. For example my Json data in String type appears correctly formatted in the browser without having to use <br/>

Comment: @cYn I don't know what browser you're using, but none of mine will show \n as a new line.

Comment: This is where I needed to see some code. Did you actually have to append "\n" in your Java code? Or did you allow the user to just press enter and store all that text that the user entered in a String?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but this will work. If the view accepts a string parameter `str`, then `@Html(HtmlFormat.escape(str).toString.replace("\n", "<br />"))` will first escape the string, then replace all instances of \n with `<br />`, and lastly transform it back to html so that Play doesn't try to escape already escaped characters. If you want to also escape \r or \r\n you could chain another `replace` onto that, or use a regex instead.

Comment: Well, I would have expected that the framework would provide some utils for such a common use case. Anyway, it's nice to know that there is at least easy way to access a HTML "escaper". Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the Play API that seemed like a better option, but perhaps there is one. For convenience it might be better to wrap this into another function.

Answer (score 0):

First escape the text, afterwards replace the line breaks with `<br>`. The `<br>` will not be replaced this way.